# web form response recording

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a macro inside of Excel in conjunction with a web form that is only available on my Intranet. I need it to pull info from an excel file table, input into the web form, click the submit button, return the confirmation to the excel doc, click the restart button and repeat the process until the 20 items have been confirmed. I have set up my file but it is not accepting my getelementbyID or getelementbyClass. I need help identifying the correct element to replace in my code... Any help would be great appreciated.

---input field---

```
<input _ngcontent-c3="" class="text-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="esn-input" placeholder="Enter Device ID" type="text">
```

---submit button---

```
<button _ngcontent-c3="" class="ui button uppercase check-device-btn">

            <!---->Check Device

            <!---->

            <!---->







          </button>
```

---confirmation message that needs to return to excel---

```
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="header center table-child-vertical-center short-desc-header">
            Confirmed
          </div>
```

----Restart button---

```
<button _ngcontent-c6="" class="massive ui circular icon button margin-left-right-30 relative restart">
      <i _ngcontent-c6="" class="icon refresh"></i>
      <span _ngcontent-c6="" class="round-button-bottom-label">Startover</span>
      <!---->
    </button>
```

This is my code so far...

```
Sub IntranetQuery()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim result As String

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "intranetpage"


        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))


    objIE.document.getElementById("esn-input").Value = _
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & " in " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value

    objIE.document.getElementById("ui button uppercase check-device-btn").Click

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    y = 2

    For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("header center table-child-vertical-center short-desc-header")

        result = aEle
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = result

        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).Value = aEle.innerText
        Debug.Print aEle.innerText

        End If

        y = y + 1

    Next

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = _
      Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B100"))

    objIE.document.getElementById("massive ui circular icon button margin-left-right-30 relative restart").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks ok `objIE.document.getElementById("esn-input").Value`, but this won't work `objIE.document.getElementById("ui button uppercase check-device-btn").Click` as I don't see anything that says "ID". It says it's a class as is this one `For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("header center table-child-vertical-center short-desc-header")`. Inspect the element again, but look further back in the code, but in the same <div> to locate the ID's for the elements you are looking for. I would need to see a lot more of the code to help.